# Access Denied error while opening file in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, filesystems, access-denied, file-access

When I try to open `window.open('file///C:\calendar.html')` it throws

> Access Denied error

How do I fix this? Thanks

Comment: What is the context?  Where is this Javascript code located?

Comment: Are you going to accept one of the answers below? :D \*jumps\*

Answer (score 4):

Could it be that the colon is missing?

`'file:///C:\calendar.html'`

Edit: Might also need to do only two forward slashes, and escape the backslash: `'file://C:\\calendar.html'`. Not sure you can open local files via JavaScript though, like the other answer says.

Answer (score 4):

Usually you'll won't be allowed to open files from the client's filesystem as this would pose a huge security hole. No browsers would allow it.

You could use signed scripts to do that. For a detailed description check:
http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/components/signed-scripts.html
This is of course browser specific.

Comment: Why is it a security hole? The browser is trying to open a program in your local PC. I dont get it.

Comment: Because any attacker could write javascript that runs on the victim's computer, reads confidential files and sends the content to the attacker.